# Code-Sign an Authenticode PE file using keys in a HSM in Linux

Tags: linux, code-signing, portable-executable, hsm, authenticode

I need a non-windows (linux or FreeBSD) way of signing a boot executable(EFI binaries) in the Authenticode PE format.

Currently there are some tools like `pbsign`, `sbsign`, `uefisign`, `osslsigncode` on *nix platforms, but the common pattern is they all need access to the private key.

My private key is in a HSM and I have a python tool that can interface with the HSM and get the output of signing a hash, with the private key in the HSM (which from my research is a step that all the PE signing tools do, though with explicit access to the private key).

Currently the HSM folks have a Thales tool for windows which works with the official Microsoft `signtool` on windows. But this is a lot of setup and non-portable solution. Also we need to maintain Windows Server Licences, etc.

How do I combine these steps (create an Authenticode PE file, but outsource the signing part alone to my python program) into something that can run on a *nix platform?

The HSM and its interface are non-negotiable (basically that choice is out of my hands).

Any pointers/ideas would be nice.

Comment: You're probably out of luck.  "Authenticode is a Microsoft-specific signing technology ..." so the first question an HSM vendor is going to ask is... why would we (as a vendor) supply tools for *nix, when this is something MS specific? Why not just use Windows?..."

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Jsign](https://github.com/ebourg/jsign) which is a pure Java implementation of Authenticode signing (disclaimer: I'm the author). It works fine on Linux, you'll just need a PKCS#11 module for your specific HSM. To use it you create a [SunPKCS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) configuration file specifying the path to the PKCS#11 module, and then call Jsign:

```
jsign --storetype PKCS11 --keystore myhsm.cfg --storepass secret --alias keyname \ 
      --certfile certificate.p7b application.exe
```